# Finding Partial Match with a List in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I got two columns of data now.

**//A list of name of authors  in Column A:**

```
A1: Harry LT, Vera CC, John MF
A2: Ken UY
A3: Anna J, Ben KF
```

**// I got another HUGE list of names like this in Column B:**

```
B1: John MF    
B2: Ken UY
B3: Fred KF
```

---

How do I find the partial match to return true/false. I have been trying to use

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&A1&"*")>0
```

But this function only catch **Ken UY** in A2, but not **John MF** in A1

Is there a function that can catch all the partial match despite space and commas in between.

I am trying to find whether the authors in Column A has a match on my list of names in Column B

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you have confused the range and match columns. What works for me with your data is `=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")>0`.

Comment: This formula: **=IFERROR(FIND(B1,A1),"False")**

Comment: Are you matching just on the same row (B value contained in A value for that row), or any value from column B matching in any value contained in column A, or something else?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am matching the value just on the same row

Comment: The wording is still confusing because you describe the columns differently (a list of names in A vs. a HUGE list of names in B).  This implies that the columns do not contain matching numbers of records, and there is no relationship between the records in each column.  Further, your formula compares an entire column to a single cell.  Also, the last sentence in the question says you want to find whether the authors in col A have a match to your list in col B, which suggests that the columns are independent and the match is not 1:1.

Comment: What I infer is that you want to check each name in column `B` to see if it occurs in one or more of the entries in column `A`, and my formula does this when copied down another column (eg `C`). If this is not what you want, please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate and ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) to see if the one is in the other:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$3,A1))))>0
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this formula as well, but it turns out to show "True" for every column

Comment: Then please show more data.  With the two you have shown it should show TRUE for both lines.

Comment: @Eruke see addition.  I added a photo to show it correctly returns FALSE

Comment: Because I got a huge list of names, will the abbreviation be causing the problem?

Comment: @Eruke with your new data I get `FALSE` for the third like I should.

Comment: @Eruke if the spelling is not exact right down the the number of spaces between the name and the second part it will return FALSE.

Comment: do you mean deleting the space and the commas within column A and B

Comment: No, if there is two spaces between `John` and `MF` in column B then it will not find a match if there is only one in Column A.  But that would give false negatives not false positives.  As to why your experience is different I cannot say without more data.